# Nginx dynamic nesting folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Nginax locations i need nesting url work for wordpress installetion dynamically

- example.com/
- example.com/folder1/
- example.com/folder1/folder2
- example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3
- example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
- .......... and so on

My locations:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This is wrlong for

- example.com/
- example.com/folder1/
- example.com/folder1/folder2

Not working example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3

Any one help me for dynamic nesting folder locations

Thanks

Comment: You don't need anything else than `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }` and a PHP handler `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` to host a WordPress site. All the WordPress routes should be handled by the WordPress code invoked via `/index.php?$args`.

Comment: i update to 
[code]
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

 # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
 }[/code]

But now the site argument not working

When i add an argument it load the root folder index.php file

Any ide?